# design pattern, architecture for multi level viewcontroller containment

Tags: swift, design-patterns, architecture

Part of an iOS application I'm working on consists of multi level view controller containment. similar to this diagram [image: view controller containment]

I'm trying to setup the interaction/ routing in a way that isolates each child controller to it's own scope and communication between is handled through a central router in "master vc". Only one single child in the diagram is visible to the user at a time. Each child belongs to a parent controller where those parents (orange color) are managed by master vc. Master doesn;t need to know all about each children as they're encapsulated within their respective parent controllers (orange).

As an example, if an event on child-A needs to present child-X with some data, it will inform master's router instead of talking directly to child-X.

Not really looking for a complete solution but rather an advice towards a suitable design pattern or communication mechanism that supports the isolation of child controllers to their scopes and tidy up the managing of controllers.

using swift 3 (no reactive programming)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions of how you could do this: (I would use protocols myself)

**Protocols:** https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

In short terms: your masterVC could implement a protocol in which all the children can use

**NotificationCenter:**
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter

Your masterVC listens listens to several "notification-names", while all the children sends out notifications.